# Is it a good practice to create a folder in /?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

I'm currently working on a project where some install script of some other teams are creating a lot of files/scripts and others various stuff in a folder located in `/`. **eg: /installfolder**

Is that considered bad practice ? Wouldn't be better to store everything in `/opt/lovelyfolder` instead ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would not be in line with the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03.html#purpose2):

> There are several reasons why creating a new subdirectory of the root filesystem is prohibited:
>
> - It demands space on a root partition which the system administrator may want kept small and simple for either performance or security reasons.
> - It evades whatever discipline the system administrator may have set up for distributing standard file hierarchies across mountable volumes.
>
> Distributions should not create new directories in the root hierarchy without extremely careful consideration of the consequences including for application portability.

The correct place for add-on applications is `/opt/<provider>`:

> /opt is reserved for the installation of add-on application software packages.
>
> A package to be installed in /opt must locate its static files in a separate /opt/ or /opt/ directory tree, where  is a name that describes the software package and  is the provider's LANANA registered name.